# GPO .bat file not working logoff/shutdown delete files and folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10, group-policy, gpo

I am trying to create a simple batch file to delete a folder and/or its contents for a user when they logoff or shutdown.

The GPO itself is working and running, I know this because it first creates a .txt document before running the delete commands.

batch file is called "delete.bat"

The GPO first copies over the batch file to C:\delete.bat. the GPO does this every time all the time.

it is set to run this file on either shutdown or logoff.  right now it only runs on shutdown.

i have several versions of this file

```
echo.>"C:\Users\myactualname\testyoyo.txt

del "C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\*.*" /s /f /q
@RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\"

exit
```

.

```
@echo off
sleep 4
echo.>"C:\Users\myactualname\testyoyo.txt"
sleep 2

set fld=C:\Users\myactualname\cpsi\data_4\
for /f %%a in ('dir %fld% /b /a-d') do echo del "%fld%%%a"
for /f %%a in ('dir %fld% /b /ad') do echo rmdir /s /q "%fld%%%a%"
```

.

```
@echo off
echo.>"C:\Users\myactualname\testyoyo.txt"
@echo off
rem Delete all files and subfolders in directory for temporary files
rem of current user account, but keep the directory itself. Temporary
rem files and subdirectories currently in use are silently ignored.
del /F /Q "C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\*" 2>nul
for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\*") do rd /Q /S "%%~D" 2>nul

rem Do the same as above for system temporary files directory.
rem This cleanup requires administrator privileges.
del /F /Q "C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\*" 2>nul
for /D %%D in ("C:\Users\%username%\cpsi\data_4\*") do rd /Q /S "%%~D" 2>nul
```

i also ran some other version which i haven't documented.  I've tried hardcoding the file paths for testing and using the %username% wildcard.

on shutdowns it will create the txt file but not on logoffs.  and at no time will it delete the files/folders.

the bat files all run fine if manually run.

i am pretty sure the file permissions are good.
however i suspect permissions is what i suspect is the problem.

thanks!!!

Comment: firstly, you can use `%userprofile%` instead of the long `c:\users\%username%` string.. then to get to the issue. where exactly in GPO did you setup this script? to test which user do in the script `echo Test>"%userprofile%\test.txt"` and then shutdown/logoff then see in which userprofile the file gets created.

Comment: If it is set to run somefile.bat and the user has .bat files associated with their editor, your script will not run, but the editor will.  If you set it to run `%comspec% /c somefile.bat`, then it should work.

Comment: So after doing nothing to it while on vacation I came back and it is working.   The three people besides myself that make GPOs all say that they made no changes in our environment.  Running across the IT depts OU on all computers.  Thank you both for your comments I have noted them and will be using both in my next GP that i am writing.